# Python/mechanize on javascript page with csrf

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize, csrf

I want to use python/mechanize to control my modem/router box. While I can login and navigate through the menus, I am not able to change any value (browser submit has no effect). The pages use javascript, but I think that I did the equivalent with mechanize in my script. Can it be it because of the *antiCSRF.js* file inclusion that prevents me to change any value?

The html/js code of the page:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function main_reboot_button()
        {
            var confrm = confirm("Do you want to continue...")
            if(confrm){         
                document.getElementById("main_reboot").value = "1";
                document.getElementById("main-reboot-form").submit();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel-body panel-align">
<div class="panel panel-default accor_brd accor_brd_RB_Curved content_blk">
  <form method="post" action="bbox-maintenance.lp" id="main-reboot-form" style="padding-top:20px;">
  <div class="control_blk clearfix">
    <input type="hidden" name= "main_reboot" id="main_reboot" value="0"></input>
    <label for="input01" class="control-label txt-head">Reboot Modem</label>
    <button class="btn_proximus_standalone" onclick='return main_reboot_button()'>Restart</button>
  </div>
  </form> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/antiCSRF.js'></script>
```

The antiCSRF.js file:

```
function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
 return null;
}
var forms=document.getElementsByTagName("form");
var rn = readCookie('xAuth_SESSION_ID');
for (var i=0; i<forms.length; i++)
{
  var temp = document.createElement("INPUT");
  temp.type = "hidden";
  temp.name = "rn";
  temp.value = rn;
  forms[i].insertBefore(temp, forms[i].firstChild);
}
```

The part of the python code I use to make the request (after login stuff):

```
browser.open("http://192.168.1.1/bbox-maintenance.lp")    
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form.find_control("main_reboot").readonly = False
browser.form['main_reboot'] = "1"
browser.submit()
```

As a result, the box is not rebooted while it should have been. The python script shows no error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution (by understanding better how works antiCSRF). I need to read the cookie value, add a new element with name 'rn' to the form and set it to the cookie value.

Adding those lines after browser.select_form does the trick:

```
browser.form.new_control('text','rn',{'value':''})
browser.form.fixup()
browser.form['rn'] = cj[0].value
```